# Dangling participle "Growing up in Missouri, they would kind of take us out into the woods"?

Tags: present-participles, dangling-participle

> Growing up in Missouri, they would kind of take us out into the woods.  (From [TED](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eup2J0oAq9Y), beginging at the first 16 second )

I think this sentence is not syntactically right as it makes the mistake of "dangling participle." The subject of "growing" should be the narrator or his peers, instead of the unidentified "they."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the participle phrase applies to **us**. The sentence would be clearer as "When we were growing up in Missouri,..." It's a misplaced modifier, though it does have a reference in the sentence.

In the continuation of the sentence, he says "they would give **you** a map...", so he's not speaking very carefully.
Also, the phrase "**kind of** take us out into the woods" is odd. Either they took them out into the woods, or they didn't.

He's not a speaker you should imitate.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I listened to this cause he's a native speaker. But as you said, he's not good, so could u recommend some listening material, preferably with subtitle, that's suitable for me?

Comment: I don't say don't listen to it, just don't imitate it. Most TED talks are better expressed than that.